# Django Inner Join and Left Join Query

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I am trying to slove the problem for Inner Join and Left Join in Django ORM.

My Models

```
class Student(models.Model):
    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=False, default='')
    Code = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, default='')
    Active = models.CharField(max_length=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
        

class Teacher(models.Model):
    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    StudentID = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    createdUser = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    createdDate = models.DateTimeField()
    UpdatedUser = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    UpdatedDate = models.DateTimeField()
    To_StudentId = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Subjects = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
```

I was tried with below ORM Query but I am not getting Proper Result Set.

```
statusFiles = Teacher.objects.filter( 'To_StudentId').select_related('StudentID')
```

My SQL Native Query is below

```
SELECT T.Name, T.Code, T.createdDate AS ProcessDate, 
ifnull(S1.Code,'All') As HomeTution, ifnull(S2.Code,'All') As TOTution, 
if(Active = 1, 'Success', 'Failure') As Status,
FROM Teacher T
INNER JOIN Student S1 ON S1.ID=T.StudentID
LEFT JOIN Student S2 ON S2.ID=T.To_StudentId
where T.Subjects IN ('Maths','English') order by T.ID desc;
```

Could you please help me any one how to achievethis by using ORM Django.